# Java Android. Отправка POST запроса с текстом и изображением с помощью OkHttp

Tags: php, java, android, okhttp

Нужно POST запросом отправить на сервер данные, а именно - 3 строки и изображение. Использую библиотеку OkHttp, вот сам код:

```
    static void uploadImage() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
    try {

        final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG = MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");

        RequestBody req = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("param1", "test1")
                .addFormDataPart("param2", "test2")
                .addFormDataPart("param3", "test3")
                .addFormDataPart("param_img", "IMG_20200903_133732.jpg",
                RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG, "storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200903_133732.jpg"))
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://mysite.ru/test.php")
                .post(req)
                .build();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        Log.d("response", "uploadImage:" + response.body().string());

    } catch (UnknownHostException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("testtest", "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("testtest", "Other Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Пока что прописываю сразу конкретный путь к конкретной картинке на телефоне для теста.
В итоге на сервере картинка оказывается вот в таком виде, не открывается и по факту картинкой не является:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Остальные данные (строковые) приходят, в базу добавляются, с ними проблем нет.
Вот **принимающий php-файл**, может в нём что-то не так:

```
<?php

include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['param1']) && isset($_POST['param2']) && isset($_POST['param3'])){
    
        $test111 = $_POST['param1'];
        $test222 = $_POST['param2'];
        $test333 = $_POST['param3'];
    

            $uploaddir = '../img_message/';
            $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['param_img']['name']);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['param_img']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);

        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO test_table (one, two, three) VALUES ('$test111', '$test222', '$test333')");
        
}

mysqli_close($connection);
```

Подскажите, в чём может быть моя ошибка.

Comment: Не вижу чтобы вы передавали файл - в вашем коде вы передаете строку!

Comment: Во всех примерах с отправкой изображений сходный код в плане указания имени файла и пути. Но если так, как это исправить?

Comment: например так: `RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG, new File("storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200903_133732.jpg"))`

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось!

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, кажется, ваш комментарий можно в ответ превратить)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка заключалась в том, что `"storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200903_133732.jpg"` является типом данных `String` , а нужно отправлять тип данных `File`.

Т.е. нужно было заменить строку:

```
RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG, "storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200903_133732.jpg"))
```

На

```
RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG, new File("storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200903_133732.jpg"))
```